# solution of Diofantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find number of non-negative integer solutions of equation:
**$x+y^2+z=x^2z+y$**.

I have tried to rearrange it like $x^2z-y^2=x-y+z$, but I don't have an idea what to do in the next step. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There are infinitely many integer solutions $(x,y,z)=(0,t,-t^2+t)$ where $t\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @mathlove, he threw in the condition "non-negative" about three minutes after your comment.

Comment: An infinite family of solutions: $x=4,\qquad y=15k+8,\qquad z=15k^2+15k+4$.

Comment: Another [goldmine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Y5H.png) is $x=40.~$ Then we have $x=6k-2,~$ where $k\in\{10,16,22,25,40,52,67,\ldots\}.$

Comment: @Lucian: All these $x$ belong to infinite families.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let,

$$x+y^2+z = x^2z+y\tag1$$

As Lucian points out, the solvable $x$ (so far) are,

$$x = 4, 40, 58, 94, 130, 148, 238, 310, 400,\dots$$

For example, looking at $x=40$, one has to find positive integers to solve,

$$y = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{6396z-159}\right)$$

The first few are,

$$z = \color{blue}{28}, \color{red}{70}, \color{green}{1000}, \color{b}{1204}, \color{blue}{2050}, \color{red}{2338}, \color{green}{5128}, \color{b}{5578},\color{blue}{7270}, \color{red}{7804}, \color{green}{12454}, \color{b}{13150},\dots$$

where it seems every *fourth* solution is in a polynomial progression. After inspecting $x=40$ and others, one can make a general conclusion.

***Theorem***. "If $y_0, z_0$ is a solution to $(1)$, then,

$$y = y_0 + (x^2 - 1) k$$

$$z = z_0 + (2y_0 - 1) k + (x^2 - 1) k^2$$

is also a solution for any $k$, thus yielding an infinite family."

**Example**, $x = 40$:

1. First with $y_0,\, z_0 = 212,\,28$:
   $$y= 212 + 1599 k = 212, 1811, 3410,\dots\\ 
   z=28 + 423 k + 1599 k^2 = 28, 2050, 7270,\dots$$
2. Second with $y_0,\, z_0 = 335,\,70$:
   $$y= 335 + 1599 k = 335, 1934, 3533,\dots\\ 
   z=70 + 669 k + 1599 k^2 = 70, 2338, 7804,\dots$$

and so on for four infinite families.

*Note*: I haven't checked if each solvable $x$ yields multiple quadratic families that yield distinct $z$.

Comment: For $x=4$, the smallest solutions are $z = 4, 34, 94, 184, 304, 454, 634,\dots$ hence it seems there is _only one_ family $z = 4+15k+15k^2$, the one given by Lucian.